# switching R version for installing a package

Tags: r

I am using R on a mac.

I am trying to install a package but it is not available in the version that I have.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'ETC...' is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
```

How can I use an older version in order to install this package.

Comment: If you google [`r project install older version`](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+project+install+older+version), there are links about installing previous versions of packages for R, and for finding older versions of R for your operating system. If you go to the source, https://r-project.org, and click through the "download" links, eventually you'll see https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/, where all previous versions of R are available. But frankly, this is usually the ***wrong approach***, depending on the package you want.

Comment: If you are on macOS, RSwitch is a menu bar applet for switching R versions https://rud.is/rswitch/

Comment: Why are the dots ("...") in the name? That doesn't seem right. There is an [ETC package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ETC) which doesn't have a min R version. You should be able to install it in R 3.6.0. I think something it wrong with the command where you are trying to install it.

Comment: This might be an XY problem. You have not told us **why** you want that package installed on what is already a very out of date R version. There might be other ways of achieving access to "old code".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa